# What is the performance impact of having 2-3 chained BaseFragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I was wondering if it's a bad practice to have a Fragment that extends a BaseCategoryFragment that also extends a BaseFragment.

BaseFragment is an abstract class that has some methods that are useful in all fragments in my app, BaseCategoryFragment extends BaseFragment and has some methods that are used only by a group of fragments.

Is there any antipattern or performance impact of having them chained like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm really concerned about performance what I do is micro-benchmarks. Not the ideal, but it will show you any big impact if there is one.

Now, about subclassing there is no noticeable performance degradation as far as I can tell.
Your main decision here should be about design, having a common parent class is quite a common pattern on that aspect on Android, BUT, you need to be really careful on that, because it's quite common to overuse it and turn those classes on god classes.
What I personally tend to do is to have a super class but completely avoid adding anything at them, and even if I have to, I will make it through a decorator or adapter or some other way to not keep any actual logic in there.

Also research about some other patterns like MVVM, that will help a lot structuring your base.